# Jenkins: SSH Server as Choice Parameter

Tags: jenkins, extended-choice-parameter

I would like the Jenkins job to have a choice parameter (pull-down) containing the SSH servers in the Configuration page under *Publish over SSH*.
Are those servers retrievable via an array variable so that I could use the extensible choice parameter?

Alternatively, if there were such a variable, I could write a simple for-loop that would perform some action on each server.

Answers I've seen so far in SO refer to using the string input parameter for SSH servers.
TIA

GF

Comment: It appear it will involve calling `public BapSshHostConfiguration getConfiguration` as found [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/publish-over-ssh-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/jenkins/plugins/publish_over_ssh/descriptor/BapSshPublisherPluginDescriptor.java)

Answer (score 0):

I found it with a little more research and code trial and error:

```
import jenkins.model.*
import jenkins.plugins.publish_over_ssh.BapSshHostConfiguration
def inst = Jenkins.getInstance()
def publishSsh = inst.getDescriptor("jenkins.plugins.publish_over_ssh.BapSshPublisherPlugin")
def hostConfigs = publishSsh.getHostConfigurations()
return hostConfigs.name
// or, if you prefer, return hostConfigs.hostName
```